# "I waited 4 years to see SS2" vs "I had to wait 4 years to see SS2"

Tags: tense, past-perfect, past-simple

My friend and I were talking about a movie called **"Attack on Titans"**. The **SS1** sequel began airing in  2013 while **SS2** began airing in 2017.

I want to say this to my friend, but I don't have a better way to say it. Could anyone show me a better way to say this?

Answer (score 1):

You could say that SS1 **launched** or **came** **out** in 2013 while SS2 **came out** in 2017.

> I waited 4 years for SS2 to **come out**.
>
> I had to wait 4 years until SS2 **came out**.

As for **"I had to wait"** vs **"I waited**" they mean pretty much the same thing with a slight difference in **"I had to"** which would imply that you were **obligated** to wait, there was nothing you could do about it. You just **had to wait.**